# How to overlap series in ggplot group by year in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, group-by, time-series

I'd like to create chart representing time series (xts object) by days and months in `ggplot` to compare trends over years.

Here how i create dataset:

```
sales_ <- read_csv("sales.csv")
sales_ <- sales_ %>% mutate(date_ = as_date(date_))

sales_xts <- xts(sales_[!names(sales_) %in% 'date_'], order.by = sales_$date_)

head(sales_xts)
                x1     x2
2017-01-02      10  20000.89
2017-01-03     100  90000.53
2017-01-04     120 100000.16
    ---         --     --
2018-01-06      16  10000.25
2018-01-09     180 100000.68
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr` and `ggplot`:

```
library(dplyr);library(ggplot2);
sales_xts %>%
    gather("key", "value", -date) %>% # gathers your data in the correct long format
# key will contain the names of x1 and x2 (you can change it)
# value will contain the numbers of each
# I supposed you have a column of dates named "date" change that with the correct name
    ggplot(aes(x = date, y = value, color = as.factor(key))) +
    geom_line(size = 1)
```